# Lists to dictionary but with multiple values for each key

Tags: python

Im gathering the following data filenames, usernames and passwords. This data is being gathered by traversing each dir looking for documents(scripts mostly) with credentials in clear text. The idea is to gather evidence of bad practices being followed by system admins.

The my script does this well enough, however I am trying to understand the best way to handle the data. Id like to place the filename and credentials found in that particular file into a dictionary. So the key being the filename and the values being the credentials found in that file.

Ive worked out how to add data to dictionaries but im not entirely sure how to and cant find a way to get 2 lists into a dictionary and the dictionary hosting multiple values for 1 key. Any pointers would be appreciated. The line with `#if not m: add non matched data to un_matched list` is currently not used, as suggested by the comment. Id like to add non matched data to another list (for debugging)

**Code**

```
dirt = "~/Desktop/tmp"

def get_files():
    regs = ["(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)", "(.*)((U|u)ser(.*))(\s=\s\w+)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))\s=\s(\W(.*)\W)", "(.*)((P|p)ass(.*))(\s=\s\W\w+\W)"]
    combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regs) + ")"
    cred_results = []
    creds = []
    un_matched = []
    filesfound = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirt):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
                readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
                for line in readfile:
                    m = re.match(combined, line)
                    if m:
                        creds.append(m.group(0))    
                   #if not m: add non matched data to un_matched list
                filesfound.append(os.path.join(root, filename)) 
                cred_results = [line.rstrip() for line in creds]

    print cred_results
    print filesfound
```

**Current Ouput from script**

```
['strUser = "guytom"', 'strPassword = "P@ssw0rd1"', 'strUsername = "guytom2"', 'strPass = "SECRETPASSWORD"']
['~/Desktop/tmp/Domain/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript1.vbs', '~/Desktop/tmp/Domain/Policies/{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}/USER/Scripts/Logon/logonscript2.bat']
```

Comment: what will be keys and what will be values?

Comment: As suggested in the post the key will be the filename and the values the credentials found in that file. The output shows credentials found and the files were found in.

Comment: I think a better way to handle it would be to add the dictionary items as the data is gathered rather than after placed in their individual lists. However Im not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: I added an answer, I am not 100 percent sure where you want to add the data but using dict.setdefault will allow you to append multiple values for each key in your dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict with dict.setdefault:

```
    d = {} # create dict 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirt):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):
                readfile = open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r")
                d.setdefault(filename,[]) #  set default value to a list
                for line in readfile:
                    m = re.match(combined, line)
                    if m:
                        creds.append(m.group(0))
                        d[filename].append(m.group(0).rstrip())  # append data to the key's list stripping newlines etc..
```

If you want to keep track of the unmatched data just add a second dict and using `with` which will close your files automatically:

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirt):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(('.bat', '.vbs', '.ps', '.txt')):                
                with open(os.path.join(root, filename), "r") as readfile:
                    matched_d.setdefault(filename,[])
                    unmatched_d.setdefault(filename,[])
                    for line in readfile:
                        m = re.match(combined, line)
                        if m:
                            creds.append(m.group(0))
                            d[filename].append(m.group(0).rstrip()) 
                        else:
                            unmatched_d[filename].append(add_data_here)
```

Comment: arrr soo simple. I read about it in the docs but i didnt think to use it like that lol Thanks Padriac. Ive not tried using it yet but your example above looks spot on. Will give you feedback in a few

Comment: It may need some work, as I said I was not certain what exact data you wanted or if you will have repeated filenames, you could probably just use `d[filename] = []` instead of setdefault if you won't have repeated filenames but the logic should do what you need,

Comment: thanks its working great. Just working out how to strip the `\n\r` from the dictionary now. ^_^

Comment: from the values? Try `m.group(0).rstrip()`

Comment: yeah just googling it now. Think a dictionary comprehension is the way to do it but just working out the justs of it.

Comment: `rstrip` should remove newlines etc.. better to remove before you add

Comment: I went with `if m: d[filename].append(m.group(0).rstrip())`

Comment: Arr, regarding your input on the unmatched data. I wasnt sure how to add the data to the dictionary as I coudnt specify what is to be added lol. What would I place in the `add_data_here`

Comment: I was not sure what you wanted as there would if m was None then there is simply nothing to add, I just added it as it was in your question!